# Do I need to install Microsoft Enterprise Library on client machine to run the application?

Tags: c#-2.0

I am creating a stand alone application for a client and I am going to use Microsoft Enterprise Library. My question is do I need to install Microsoft Enterprise Library on client machine too for the application to work?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you shouldn't need to install it on the client machine, as long as you include the dependent DLLs with your installer.

If the references have "Copy Local" set to true, when you build your application, it will copy the DLLs to your output directory, and so it will not need them installed in the GAC.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to "install" it separately per se, you just have to copy the DLL to where your application's assembly is installed at. Depending on your settings, visual studio already does this for you.